# Is it legitimate to calculate a time bw 2 events using this method?

Tags: speed-of-light

Imagine a rocket moving on a straight line, passing by me (observer on Earth) at constant speed $v$ and going straight towards an asteroid located at distance $L$ (from me).

At time $0$ (as it runs past me), the rocket emits a beam of light towards the asteroid, which is reflected by the asteroid and returns back to the rocket.

This is to illustrating:

[image]

I thought I could simply calculate times and distances (in the observer's rest frame) using a `distance versus time` plot such as the following:

[image]

where the orange lines are the moving beams at speed $c$ (one way and return) and the green line is the moving rocket at speed $v$.

From there it looks that the beam returns to the rocket at time $2L / (c+v)$, when the rocket has traveled distance $2Lv / (c+v)$ (time and distance calculated in the "rest" frame of the observer).

Can I do it this way, or does it imply problems of consistency?

Any hint much appreciated.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/789663/2451

Comment: I'm a little sorry that no one has the slightest comment on the situation described...

Comment: Hi Andrew. Welcome to Phys.SE. You might try asking in a chat room, such as e.g. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/ or https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/